# Could not cast value of type in get notification userInfo

Tags: swift, xcode

Why does an error appear here?

```
if let tskNum = notification.userInfo!["NUM"] {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tskNum as! Int, section: 0)
}
```

Error: Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String'

Comment: You can't cast from String to Int, you need to convert it. Do `Int(tskNum)` ore even better `if let tskNum = notification.userInfo!["NUM"], let index = Int(tskNum) { let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` type of `userInfo` is `Any`, you have to downcast `Any` to `String` first and then **convert** `String` to `Int`.

```
if let tskNum = notification.userInfo?["NUM"] as? String,
   let row = Int(tskNum) {
      let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
}
```

If you are responsible for the `userInfo` dictionary why do you pass a `String` value?

Answer (score 0):

Casting is incorrect, you can't get an integer value from a string(auto typecasting is not possible). Please update -

```
if let tskNum = notification.userInfo!["NUM"], let index = Int(tskNum) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
}
```